# Google Analytics API with Zend

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, google-analytics

I am looking for easiest way to receive data from Google Analytics and I found this library, but it seems not working after changes in API.

http://healthycod.in/2011/07/google-analytics-and-zend-framework/

I am looking for any solution that will work with current google api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This component is being added to Zend Framework in version 1.12, where it has been updated to work with the current version of the API. 1.12 isn't out yet but there is a release candidate available if you can't wait: http://framework.zend.com/download/latest (scroll down to the bottom)